# Javascript framework for handling views

Tags: javascript, view

I'm making a simple gaming platform. It's supposed to be used only on (W)LAN. One of the devices is running a node.js server, and client devices can be computers, smart phones or tablets. I'm planning to handle all the client-server communication using socket.io, as that makes it possible to have almost real-time connection and to have sessions without having to manage user accounts.

When the user joins a system on a browser, the interactioin goes like this: Starting view ---> game selection view ---> join/create game view ---> game lobby --> actual game.

The question is, what would be a good approach for changing these views? I've thought about some possibilities:

- I could load a partial web page (html-document) when a page is changed
- I could load one large html-document when joining the system and show/hide divs on a page change
- I could use some more complex framework

Which approach would be best, considering that the application will be used on mobile phones and therefore memory usage and battery life are important factors?

Comment: Ever looked at knockout? And the MVVM pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Backbone.js Views](http://backbonejs.org/#View). It's lightweight, and you can use it without using any other component from Backbone.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll try backbone.